# Who is the priest/kohen of 1 Sam 2:35?

Tags: prophecy, 1-samuel, messiah

Possible answers to this question such as David or Tsadok do not satisfy me because the former was not a priest and the latter didn't remain for ever.

> **NASB, 1 Samuel 2:35** - But I will raise up for Myself a ***faithful priest*** who will do according to what is in My heart and in My soul; and I will build him an enduring house, and ***he will walk before My anointed always***.

Comment: I suggested two edits, (a spelling in the title), and I added the verse.  I think a more important issue is whether or not the `"faithful Priest / Kohen"` is a different person from `"my anointed / Moshiakh"` ... According to the preposition "before" - they appear to be two different people - unless the translation is missing something.

Answer (score 1):

### All the days

"Always" is literally "all the days", with "which days" being unspecified. It's not the Hebrew word for "eternity", which is *olam*. Some examples of how "kol ha yamim" is used in the Bible:

Deut 4.10

> Specially the day that thou stoodest before the LORD thy God in Horeb,
> when the LORD said unto me, Gather me the people together, and I will
> make them hear my words, that they may learn to fear me **all the
> days** that they shall live upon the earth, and that they may teach
> their children.

Deut 5.29

> O that there were such an heart in them, that they would fear me, and
> keep all my commandments **always**[all the days], that it might be well with them, and
> with their children for ever!

Deut 28.29

> And thou shalt grope at noonday, as the blind gropeth in darkness, and
> thou shalt not prosper in thy ways: and thou shalt be only oppressed
> and spoiled **evermore**[all the days], and no man shall save thee.

Deut 31.13

> And that their children, which have not known any thing, may hear, and
> learn to fear the LORD your God, **as long as** ["all the days"] ye
> live in the land whither ye go over Jordan to possess it.

Judges 16.16

> And it came to pass, when she pressed him **daily** [all the days] with her words, and
> urged him, so that his soul was vexed unto death;

1 Sam 1.28

> Therefore also I have lent him to the LORD; **as long as he liveth** ["all the days"] he
> shall be lent to the LORD. And he worshipped the LORD there.

Thus this idiom can be used to specify "all the days" of your life, or "all the days" a people live in the land, or "all the days" you are being punished, or "all the days" someone is nagging you. E.g. generally a condition follows "all the days", and if no condition is supplied in the text, it must be obtained from context.

### Fulfillment according to the natural

Thus like all prophecies there is a more or less immediate fulfillment in the flesh and then a type for something spiritual. If it was only an immediate fulfillment and no spiritual type, we wouldn't regard it as scripture but would only view it as having historical interest.

So the immediate fulfillment would be Samuel who walks faithfully "all the days" before God's annointed, first Saul and then David. Here, the condition for "all the days" would be all the days of Samuel's life in which Saul or David were annointed.

But because there is a spiritual type that is eternal, the condition for "all the days" is left out, which is a hint that this is a prophecy of something more than Samuel's lifetime.

### Intepretation of "mine annointed"

Historically, being annointed was a type for being set aside for God's ministry. The following were annointed:

- Priest (and his garments)
- King
- Prophet
- Sacrificial animal
- ark of testimony
- tabernacle
- table of showbread
- candlesticks in temple
- altar of incense
- brazen altar of sacrifice
- laver for washing
- all other vessels (kli) in the tabernacle

I think this is a complete list (but am open to corrections if missed something).

Now *all of these* represent *ministries* performed by Christ. E.g. Christ is the king that is the head of creation, the priest that reconciles man to God, the lamp that lights the world, the bread of God that comes from heaven, a vessel of God, the laver from which pours the living water, the tabernacle of God, etc. Thus if we look through the old testament and see all the things that were annointed, we get a complete view of all the ministries of the annointed one, that is Christ. Also in the old testament, the phrase "mine annointed" usually refers to "king" (e.g. in the books of Samuel and Kings) but could also refer to prophet, priest, or even messiah, depending on context.

### Spiritual interpretation of priest walking before mine annointed

The typeology in this passage is of the priest walking before the king. It can't be the priest walking before messiah, as the messiah is also the priest. Thus we are talking about different ministries of Christ.

"all the days" is thus a continual, endless service of the priest reconciling man to God in front of the king. The priest has to be performing this ministry otherwise man would be an enemy of God and the king would be at war, and thus would not rule over all; because if one is at war, then there is something that has not yet been put under the feet of the king, but although the prophecy for the flesh is partial, the prophecy for the spirit is perfect and complete.

Therefore as long as the flesh exists - e.g. as long as time exists and there are "days" - then the priest has to be walking before the king. This is the spiritual interpretation of the prophecy.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that (1 Sam 2:35) is a multi-prophetic proclamation? To elaborate, God revelation to Priest Eli in  (1 Sam 2:35) could refer to Prophet Samuel who would rise up in the near future within the context of Eli’s time period.  However, it could also refer to Jesus Christ, the priest who will be associated with eternity.  Is that a correct evaluation of (1 Sam 2:35)?

Answer (score 0):

The word 'before' לפני is literally ' to/for the face of where 'face' is a metaphor for the seen part of the personality. The face represents the person.

There is no reason to conclude that the priest is different from the Meshiach. The Priest is simply another 'view' of the Messiah.

Comment: The word לפני always mean "in front of", or "before", either temporally or positionally. It never means "to the face of" or "for the face of" (whatever that means) in any verse. So the claim in this post based on such a translation is not supportable.

Comment: The פ is described as a kaf with two yods. One visible, one invisible. It represents the speaking of invisible things through things which are seen. As such is is the visible face of the hidden: the riddle, the metaphor, the prophecy, the mystery.  Though I prefer not to directly reference some of the rabbis, you may wish to dig deeper before making blanket pronouncements. Absolute statement of negatives are really dangerous.  The nun is the symbol of Mashiach. As some say, the sod is mashiach s well.

Comment: That is not hermeneutics, it's some type of kabbalistic speculation. The form of the letter פ as a כ with a י is a change that was made in the late middle ages, and only in the Ashkenazic script, not in the Sepharadic or Yemenite scripts. You wont find such a פ in any of the ancient OT manuscript images.

Comment: hermeneutics - the branch of knowledge that deals with interpretation, especially of the Bible or literary texts.  Just because you don't like the hermeneutic does not make it not a hermeneutic.  And just because you choose to believe that the most sacred writings were in the language of their enemies, there are those of us who were taught otherwise and reject the so-called 'modern' scholarship that casts doubt on the word at every turn.

Comment: And the main point of kabbalah is to learn the power of words to negate the word of God, according to Rabbi Ginsberg.  This is nothing of what I do (reveal Christ in all the scriptures), so please refrain from making wild insinuations.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that the OP has written, "David or Tsadok do not satisfy me because the former was not a priest and the latter didn't remain for ever". This is a misunderstanding of the nature of divine promise as per the OT. Divine promise in the OT is always contractual, conditioned on righteous future behavior. It is never absolute, as indicated by the text itself in I Samuel 2:30 (NIV)

> Therefore the Lord, the God of Israel, declares: ‘I promised that members of your family would minister before me forever.’ But now the Lord declares: ‘Far be it from me! Those who honor me I will honor, but those who despise me will be disdained.

The context of verse 9 (NASB) is:

> "Those who contend with the LORD will be shattered; Against them He will thunder in the heavens, The LORD will judge the ends of the earth; And He will give strength to **His king**, And will exalt the horn of **His anointed**."

The parallelism between "His king" and "His anointed" in the last line of the verse makes it clear that the anointed in this chapter refers to the secular king.

The language "he will walk before My anointed always" in verse 35 must be understood as referring to two different people. It makes no sense to say that someone walks in front of himself, not in English, not in Hebrew.

So, unfortunately, in the context of the OT, and specifically in the books of Samuel, the answer is in fact David and Tsadok. David received the eternal promise of secular kingship, which his descendants lost. Amazingly, the Tsadokean priesthood remained from the time of David, about BCE 1000, until their deposition in Hasmonean times, circa BCE 140, nearly 900 years.

In the OT, the offices of priest and king are always completely separate. Since the rightful king is Davidic and David was from the tribe of Judah he could not also be a priest, a descendant of the house of Aaron in the tribe of Levi.

Comment: How does Hannah's prayer establish the context for the man of God's condemnation of Eli? It seems like the prophecy deals with a replacement of the corrupt house of Eli with a faithful house.

Comment: @RevelationLad There is no clear connection from the prayer, only from the context of the previous verse I Samuel 1:12-14 that citicizes Eli albeit less than his sons. The prophesy in I Samuel 2:35 is a separate theme. I agree that the theme of I Samuel 2:35 is indeed the replacement of the house of Eli with a faithful house, which was in fact soon fulfilled in the house of Tsadok that lasted close to a thousand years.

Answer (score 0):

From a Christian perspective, the Messiah is the Anointed One, and 'the enduring house' are those who are obedient to him.

> “Moses was faithful as a servant in all God’s house,” bearing witness to what would be spoken by God in the future. But Christ is faithful as the Son over God’s house. And we are his house, if indeed we hold firmly to our confidence and the hope in which we glory." (Heb.3:5-6)

The 'faithful priest' is the one who is proclaimed by the LORD as 'a priest forever according to the order of Melchizedek' (Ps.110:4) Which in Christian belief is the Messiah, Jesus Christ.

The question remains, is 'he will walk before my anointed forever' to be understood as 'they will walk before my anointed forever'. In Christian belief, the 'faithful house' is known as 'the body of the Messiah'.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 0):

If you ask a Christian, they would always answer "Jesus", which doesn't make sense because the text says he will have a faithful house and will walk after his "messiah"/anointed all days (if Jesus is the character spoken about here, and also the messiah, is he chasing himself?)

Tzadok is the character that the text speaks about. As we know, the bloodline of Tzadok continued for many years (in fact, some Jewish and Samaritan families believe they are the traces of the Sadducees/Tzdokim to this day).

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).